# React to IIS always doing redirect

Tags: react-native, iis, react-router, webstorm

```
export default ({ childProps }) => (
  <Switch>
    <AuthenticatedRoute exact path={'/'} component={Home} props={childProps} />
    <UnauthenticatedRoute exact path={'/login'} component={Login} props={childProps} />
    <UnauthenticatedRoute path={"/autolink/:userId/:tempKey"} component={AutoLink} props={childProps} />
  </Switch>
);
```

```
    <rewrite>
          <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true"> 
                    <match url=".*" /> 
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/merchant-client" /> 
                </rule> 
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Whenever I try to go to the `autolink/:userId/:tempKey` route it always redirects me to the home which by default loads the `/merchant-client/login` page.

It's weird because it works fine when I run this locally in WebStorm and GoLand, but once I had to move this to IIS it doesn't work. I had to add the URL Rewrite rule for it resolved the issue when you refresh the page it caused it to crash.

Comment: How does this relate to Go?

Comment: part of the project involves Go. This specific portion doesnt involve Go. That was my bad.